# How do I specify the line colours in geom_step()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the command for specifying the line colours in a ggplot using `geom_step()`?

The default colours are working fine, I just want to alter them to my preferred colours.

I have two groups, and my ggplot code starts:

```
ggplot(WomenAgeComparison, aes(x=IntegerAge, y=CumAgePercent, colour=DataSource)) +
geom_step()
```

The two groups plot fine. Everything works fine except for changing the line colours.

I have tried:

```
scale_color_manual(values=c("mediumorchid2",'blue'))
```

which gave the error

```
Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.
```

and didn't override the existing colours.

I also tried

```
scale_color_continuous(values=c("mediumorchid2",'blue'))
```

which gave the error

```
Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "gradient", seq_gradient_pal(low,  : 
unused argument (values = c("mediumorchid2", "blue"))
```

The example of two colours [on this page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-geom_step/) used two separate `geom_step()` lines. Surely there is an easier way?

What is the command to use? Is there a `scale_color` command to use, or should it be specified in the aesthetics bracket? If the latter, how do I do that?

Updated to show full ggplot code:

```
ggplot(WomenAgeComparison, aes(x=IntegerAge, y=CumAgePercent, colour=DataSource)) +
geom_step() +
scale_color_manual(values=c("mediumorchid2",'blue')) +
xlab("Age (years)") + ylab("Cumulative proportion") + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 20), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .2), expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_color_discrete(name = "Data source", labels = c("Synthetic data\nestimates", "Timaru Data\nrandom rounded\ncounts")) +
theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.key.height=unit(1.5, "cm"),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15))
```

I have the `scale_color_discrete` only to put in the text I want into the legend title and text. I tried to use the theme element_text options to do it instead, and couldn't get that to work.

Comment: please include your data using the `dput(your_data)` command and ading to your question

Comment: `df <-structure(list(x = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4.44444444444444, 6.88888888888889, 9.33333333333333, 
11.7777777777778, 14.2222222222222, 16.6666666666667, 19.1111111111111, 
21.5555555555556, 24), grp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Group A", 
"Group B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))`.  Use that and `ggplot(df, aes(x,y,color=grp)) + geom_step()`.  You get two colors.

Comment: Your error message indicates that you have not provided all of your `ggplot` code... there must be another call that is creating another color scale, correct?  Or are you adjusting the color scale in some other way in addition to the `scale_color_manual` call?  If you take the example code provided in the comment above and add `scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue'))`, you should get the colors to change without issue.  Can you post the rest of your `ggplot` code?

Comment: You can't have 2 color scales. (Well, you can, but as the warning says all but the last one will be ignored.) Delete your `scale_color_discrete` and put the `name = "Data source", labels = c("Synthetic data\nestimates", "Timaru Data\nrandom rounded\ncounts")` arguments inside `scale_color_manual()`.

Comment: Thanks, I build this graphs up element by element so I didn't notice I already had a color call. Is the rule: all legend font and text content goes inside the scale color command? I find the legend manipulations archaic.